# Network (wifi) goes down and then up on ubuntu 17.04

Tags: wireless, 17.04

Having a problem I have not yet experienced. I made a fresh install of 17.04 and now I have noticed my link to internet goes down and then back up randomly.
Have noticed when I download some files via torrent, after a while speed drops down to 0 and then goes up again. THe wifi signal shows good connection but still the link goes down.
When network is down I cant access webpages or anything. If I wait 1-3 minutes everything comes back again, and after a while goes down again....arrg..

How to troubleshoot where problem is?

::::::::UPDATE:::::::::
OUTPUT OF `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak] [8086:0084]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 BGN [8086:1315]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Having other laptops and computers working perfect but this one has worked flawlessly until i installed 17.04. Now it gives me gray hair.

Comment: Guess I am the only one having issues =( 
Wifi signal is strong and I am connected to the network. Using Http sometimes takes ages to load pages and sometimes it times out. 
TSL handshake can take a LONG while.
Torrent speed goes up to 1,5Mbit/sec to drop down to 0, and then back and forward.
Streaming music via RythmBox same problem. 
Using sudo apt-get update works when line is up, but when down it times out and I get error message.

Answer (score 1):

Run in a terminal

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8"
```

and reboot.